How to Get and Delete the file from Image element source C#
Context: my end user selects an image from his computer to use as his Profile pic in my C# standalone desktop application. And the backend basically copies the image selected by the end user in the app's local folder created in User/Documents (also handled in backend).
I want to create a functionality to delete the previous image which was copied to the app's local folder in the User/Documents and not fill the folder up by keep copying new images.
The RegisterPage.xaml.cs (selection and copying the image)
private void OpenImageFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.png;)|*.png;";
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\"; // Set the initial directory (optional)
    
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string destinationFilePath;
        // Get the selected file path
        string selectedImagePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        try
        {
            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
            string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, "FT_SGS", "myschoolinfo");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
            
            // Get the file name from the selected image path
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(selectedImagePath);

            // Combine the destination folder path with the file name
            destinationFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);

            // Copy the image file
            File.Copy(selectedImagePath, destinationFilePath, true);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(destinationFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            this.schllogo.Source = bitmapImage;
            // Now you can use 'selectedImagePath' as needed (e.g., load it into an Image control)

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error processing image:\n{ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }                
    }
}

RegisterPage.xaml
<Button Click="RemoveSchlLogo" x:Name="removeschoollogo" Background="{DynamicResource WindowBrush}" Foreground="{DynamicResource Foreground}" Content="Remove logo" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="160" Margin="0,175,0,0"
        />


You can delete a file in c# with the File.Delete() method, if that is the case.
If I understand your issue correctly, you can just add this code to delete it:
if (File.Exists(your_path)) {
    File.Delete(your_path)
}

In this example, 'your_path' is your app's local folder combined with the filename for the previous image.
(You'll need to give the image a name when it's imported, so you know the path)
References:
File.Exists() - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-8.0
File.Delete() - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-8.0

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
